# Sorting arrays by key number PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort some arrays which keys are prices of products. I've used `ksort` and `krsort` and everything has worked as desired. The problem is when the number of the key has more than one figures, then it doesn't order properly.

**Array example:**

```
$array = array(
 '11,45' => 'product1',
 '8,91' => 'product2',
 '12,14' => 'product3',
 '9,54' => 'product4
);
```

**Result I got for order ascendent:**

```
11,45 - 12,14 - 8,91 - 9,54
```

**Result desired for order ascendent:**

```
8,91 - 9,54 - 11,45 - 12,14
```

Comment: `8,91` is seen as a string not an int, you have to use `8.91` so 1 is higher than 8 according to alphabetical order

Comment: I put the commas only in the example, on my code I have . and it doesn't order propertly.

Comment: try adding 5.6 and 51.0 to them to see how they will be sorted. because its still possible that it is read as strings. if it is the result will become `11,45 - 12,14 - 51.0 - 5.6 - 8.91 - 9.54` pretty much check if the sorting actually sorts alphabeticaly or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ksort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function with `SORT_NUMERIC` flag:

```
ksort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple and short solution may help you.

```
$array = array(
 '11.45' => 'product1',
 '8.91' => 'product2',
 '12.14' => 'product3',
 '9.54' => 'product4'
);

$array=array_flip($array); //flip key and values
asort($array); //sort values low to high
$array=array_flip($array); //flip the key and values again
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

This function might do the trick; it's based on splitting what is before the comma.

```
function array_sort($arr){
if(is_array($arr)){
    $numeric = array();
    $string = array();
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if(isset($v["meta_value"])){
             $str = explode(" ",trim($v["meta_value"]));
             $firstWord  = explode(",",trim($str[0]));
         }else{
             $str = $v;
             $firstWord  = explode(",",trim($str));
         }

        $firstWord = $firstWord[0];

        if(is_numeric($firstWord))
        {
            $numeric[(int)$firstWord] = $v;
        }else{
            $string[$firstWord] = $v;
        }
        unset($firstWord);
    }
    ksort($string,SORT_STRING);
    ksort($numeric,SORT_NUMERIC);

    return array_merge((array)$string, (array)$numeric);
}
return false;
}
```

The usage:

```
$meta =get_post_meta($post_id,$meta_key);
$sorted = array_sort($meta);
```